# Show that $TIME(\sqrt{n})$ = $TIME(1)$

Tags: computational-complexity

Also known as CMU 15-455, Spring 2017, Homework 2.4.

Before I ask the main questions, let me first give a sketch of my idea. First, recall the definition of big-$O$ and time complexity class $TIME(t(n))$.

- **Definition:** Let $f$ and $g$ be functions $f$, $g$: $\mathbb{N}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}^+$. Say that $f(n)$ = $O(g(n))$ if $\lim_{n
     \to \infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ = 0. In other words, $f(n) = O(g(n))$
  means that for any real number $c$ > 0, a number $n_0$ exists, where
  $f(n)$ $\leq$ $cg(n)$ for all $n \geq n_0$.
- **Definition:** Let $t: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be a function. Define the time complexity class, $TIME(t(n))$, to be the collection of all languages that are decidable by an $O(t(n))$ time Turing machine.

By definition, $TIME(\sqrt{n})$ and $TIME(1)$ are the collection of all languages that are decidable by a $O(\sqrt{n})$ and a $O(1)$ time TM respectively. My approach is the following:

**Proposition:** $TIME(1)$ is the collection of all languages that are decidable by an $O(\sqrt{n})$ time Turing machine.

If the above proposition is true, it should be sufficient to prove that $TIME(\sqrt{n})$ = $TIME(1)$. If the runtime is a constant $c$, then we can use the runtime $O(1)$ to represent $c$. Let $c = 1$ as an example. Obviously, $1$ = $O(1)$. We wish to show that $1$ = $O(\sqrt{n})$ as well.

By the definition of big-$O$, we have to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$, which is true. As such, $1$ = $O(1)$ = $O(\sqrt{n})$. As $TIME(1)$ is the collection of all languages that are decidable by an $O(1)$ time TM, and $O(1)$ = $O(\sqrt{n})$, the above proposition is proved. Hence $TIME(\sqrt{n})$ = $TIME(1)$.

The proof looks sound to me. However, upon further inspection, I have some problems with it:

1. The reverse approach, $TIME(\sqrt{n})$ is the collection of all
   languages decidable by an $O(1)$ time TM does not seem to work.
   Because if I understand the definition of big-$O$ correctly, are we
   trying to assert that $\sqrt{n}$ = $O(\sqrt{n})$ = $O(1)$? Then
   $\sqrt{n}$ = $1$, which is not true? What did I get wrong?
2. How can we show that $1 = O(1)$ with the definition of big-$O$
   above? $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{1} = 1 \neq 0$. And if we use
   the second version of the definition, what if $0 \leq c \leq 1$?

Those are my main question. In the case my approach is wrong, how will you approach it?

*(I have asked this question on the Computer Science Stack Exchange, but no one has given an answer yet. I figure asking here may get more responses, since the question is also math-oriented.)*

Comment: Are you working on the book "Introduction to the Theory of Computation" by M. Sipser ? In this case, why do you give instead the cryptic "CMU 15-455" reference ?

Comment: I was following the undergrad caught taught at CMU called Undergrad Complexity Theory, which is also referenced as CS 15-455. You can check it out here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/15455-s17/

Comment: But what is behind the acronym CMU ? It is not known in remote countries like my one...

Comment: It's Carnegie Mellon University. It is quite famous, enough that I have heard of it even though I do not study there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f(n)=O(g(n))$ is a dangerous notation. It isn't what it looks like. It really means $f(n)\in O(g(n)),$ that is, $f(n)$ is among the functions that belong to the class $O(g(n))$ (which is defined a little differently than what you wrote).
It doesn't even follow the most basic properties of the $=$ relation,
such as that if $a=b$ then $b=a,$ but people use this notation anyway because that's how they learned it.

It is true that if $g(n)<h(n)$ for all positive $n$ then any function that is in $O(g(n))$ is in $O(h(n))$ -- but the converse is **not** true. You found that any member of $TIME(1)$ is also a member of $TIME(\sqrt n)$, but as you noticed,
that is not the same thing as showing that any member of $TIME(\sqrt n)$
is a member of $TIME(1)$.

If you could prove both directions you would prove that the classes are equal,
but if you can show the existence of even one language that is in $TIME(\sqrt n)$
and not in $TIME(1)$ you would prove that the classes are not equal.

---

Some of your confusion is due to incorrect statements of definitions.
The first "big-O" definition you gave is actually a definition of
"little-O", $f(n) \in o(g(n)).$
In the second definition (which is **almost** the "big-O" definition),
there just needs to exist some $c$ for which the rest is true;
you do not need the rest of the statement to be true for every positive $c.$

Comment: I see your points. But do you think that my ideas are on the right track? I.e. is it possible to show that any member of $TIME(\sqrt{n})$ is a member of $TIME(1)$? 

As for the definition of big-O, Sipser's book only mentions small-$o$ notation and say that big-$O$ is the $\leq$ equivalent of small-$o$ (the $<$ version), without formally stating it. So thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You would need to prove that there are no languages that are decidable in time proportional to $\sqrt n$ that cannot be decided in constant time.

Comment: As for the first formal definition of Big-$O$ (the one using limit), what is wrong with it? Is limit not sufficient to describe Big-$O$?

Comment: The first definition is literally little-O. I don't think you can use a limit to define big-O.

Comment: As for the "converse is not true", are you saying that $g(n) > h(n)$ does not imply that any function in $O(g(n))$ is in $O(h(n))$?

Comment: That's right, for example $g(n)=n^2+1>h(n)=1$ does not imply that $O(n^2+1)$ is contained in $O(1).$ In fact $g(n)=n^2+1$ itself is a function in $O(n^2+1)$ but is not in $O(1).$